# Write a query to display the book code, book title ,supplier name and price of the book which takes maximum price based on each supplier

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to display the book code, book title ,supplier name and price of the book which takes maximum price based on each supplier.
[image: supplier details table]

[image: book details table]

```
SELECT book_code,
       book_title,
       supplier_name,
       price
FROM lms_book_details
JOIN lms_suppliers_details using(supplier_id)
GROUP BY supplier_name HAVING price IN
  (SELECT max(price)
   FROM lms_book_details
   GROUP BY supplier_id)
```

output

[image]

The output is displaying, but the book title and price are not correct.

Comment: What do you expect if book_title,supplier_name and price are same but book_code is different then that book_title has one entry only in output or two entry??

Comment: if book_title,supplier_name and price are same but book_code is different then  two entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to get the maximum price per supplier:

```
SELECT  supplier_id, MAX(Price) AS Price
FROM    lms_book_details
GROUP BY supplier_id
```

You then have your query to get all book details

```
SELECT  bd.book_code,
        bd.book_title,
        sd.supplier_name,
        bd.price
FROM    lms_book_details AS bd
        JOIN lms_suppliers_details AS sd 
            ON sd.supplier_id = bd.supplier_id;
```

So it is just a matter of combining the two to filter the results of the second query to only include the results of the first:

```
SELECT  bd.book_code,
        bd.book_title,
        sd.supplier_name,
        bd.price
FROM    lms_book_details AS bd
        JOIN lms_suppliers_details AS sd 
            ON sd.supplier_id = bd.supplier_id
        JOIN
        (   SELECT  supplier_id, MAX(Price) AS Price
            FROM    lms_book_details
            GROUP BY supplier_id
        ) AS MaxPrice
            ON MaxPrice.supplier_id = bd.supplier_id
            AND MaxPrice.Price = bd.Price;
```

**ADDENDUM**

After recreating your sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc5a5/1), then running the query above you get the following results

```
BOOK_CODE   BOOK_TITLE                  SUPPLIER_NAME       PRICE
BL0000002   Java The compete reference  ROSE BOOK STORE     750
BL0000006   Java The compete reference  ROSE BOOK STORE     750
BL0000004   Java The compete reference  SINGAPORE SHOPPEE   750
BL0000009   Fire                        KAVARI STORE        999
```

I assume "ROSE BOOK STORE" is the duplicate you are referring to, however taking your instruction:

> Write a query to display the book code, book title ,supplier name and price of the book witch takes maximum price based on each supplier.

The maximum price for "ROSE BOOK STORE" is 750.00, so we need to get the `book_code`, `book_title` for the book which takes this price. There are however two books that take this price, which one should be chosen? With no guidelines on how to make this choice, both books with this price are returned.

Comment: This *is* the easy method

Comment: thanks...its working perfectly...thank you 
 
GarethD

Comment: In this output,you missed record for this book "Java How To Do Program" .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using sub query.

Try this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc5a5/6

It has 2 queries.
On first it is also group by book_code because book_code is different.

In second query is done based on only 3 group by suppliedId,book_title and price.and book_code will be highest book_code.

Comment: i need t get the bookcode,book title and price of each supplier which has maximum price..but you have done wrong thing please chck it

Comment: But what if book_title,price and supplier are same,In Fiddle just see inserted values. In that "Java How To Do Program" book_title has three entries with same name,supplier and price.only book_code is different.

Comment: no only two books with same name and supplier and price..it should come..the third one have a different supplier name

Comment: As per your comment in question my first query in sql fiddle is given same result I think.